# How to access an object nested inside an array by the value of one of its keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

Say I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "postsConnection": {
      "groupBy": {
        "author": [
          {
            "key": "xyz",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 5
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "abc",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 3
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would one access the value of `count` corresponding to the `author` element that has, say, `xyz` as its key? I know for this particular example I could just do this:

```
const n = data.postsConnection.groupBy.author[0].connection.aggregate.count
```

But that would mean knowing in advance which element in the array holds the desired value for `key`, which isn't the case in my context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the author can appear multiple times, you can `.filter()` the array stored at `author` and then `.map()` the results to the `count`:

```js
const data = {data:{postsConnection:{groupBy:{author:[{key:"xyz",connection:{aggregate:{count:5}}},{key:"abc",connection:{aggregate:{count:3}}}]}}}};

const author = "xyz";
const res = data.data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.filter(({key}) => key === author).map(obj => obj.connection.aggregate.count);

console.log(res);

// If you want to get the total of all counts for the given author, you can use reduce on the result to sum:
const totalCountsForAuthor = res.reduce((acc, n) => acc+n, 0);
console.log(totalCountsForAuthor);
```

If the author can only appear once, you can use `.find()` instead of `.filter()` like so:

```js
const data = {data:{postsConnection:{groupBy:{author:[{key:"xyz",connection:{aggregate:{count:5}}},{key:"abc",connection:{aggregate:{count:3}}}]}}}};

const author = "xyz";
const res = data.data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.find(({key}) => key === author).connection.aggregate.count

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first instance inside an array that meets a certain condition (in your case, the first instance whose `key` value is equal to the `key` value you want).

```js
var obj = {"data":{"postsConnection":{"groupBy":{"author":[{"key":"xyz","connection":{"aggregate":{"count":5}}},{"key":"abc","connection":{"aggregate":{"count":3}}}]}}}};

function getAuthorByKey(key) {
  return obj.data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.find(author => author.key === key);
}

console.log(getAuthorByKey("xyz").connection.aggregate.count);
console.log(getAuthorByKey("abc").connection.aggregate.count);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `author` array always exists:

```js
const data = {
      postsConnection: {
          groupBy: {
              author: [{
                  key: "xyz",
                  connection: {
                      aggregate: {
                          count: 5
                      }
                  }
              }, {
                  key: "abc",
                  connection: {
                      aggregate: {
                          count: 3
                      }
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
};

function getCount(keyVal) {
    const element = data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.find(item => item.key === keyVal)
    return element.connection.aggregate.count || "";
}

console.log(getCount('xyz'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = { "data": {
    "postsConnection": {
      "groupBy": {
        "author": [
          {
            "key": "xyz",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 5
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "abc",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 3
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  };
  
  data.data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.forEach((autor) => {
  if(autor.key === "xyz")
    console.log(autor.connection.aggregate);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of array find, to find the author by "key".

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

`const author = data.postsConnection.groupBy.author.find((author) => author.key === "xyz")`

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/gmaslic/pen/wvwbLoL

Then you can access all the properties from found "author"